# How can I test a command before a pipe, capture it's output and understand if the command ran successfully or not

Tags: bash, if-statement, eval

I'm writting a script that will execute commands on different servers automatically and I am trying to log all it's content and output. I am having difficulties with redirections and command status output. Meaning was the command successfull and what is its output?

I have tried many directions such redirecting the command output to a function or file. I have tried a simple if statement. Both worked for there respected function. But when I am trying to combine both of them the script always return the command to be successfull. And to some level it is.

```
#!/bin/bash

function Executing(){
  if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    if [ $DEBUG = "true" ]; then
      echo "$1" | Debug i s
      if $1 2>&1 | Debug o o;then
        echo "$1" | Debug s r
      else
        echo "$1" | Debug e r
      fi
    else
      eval $1
    fi
  fi
}

Executing "apt-get update"
```

Also note that the system requires sudo to execute apt-get update. Thus the script should report & log an error. Right now tho, whenever I call the Executing function, the function returns a successful execution. I am pretty sure it does because of the added pipe `| debug o o` that captures the output and formats it. Which I'll later redirect to a log file.

So I tested `if apt-get update;then echo yes;else echo no; fi` which worked in my terminal. But as soon as I pipe the output to the function debug, the if statement returns true.

Comment: Try with `set -o pipefail`

Comment: That did it. Could you explained this a little further please? What does it do in terms of logic? Also can I put this at the beginning of the script or will it affect some behavior of bash?

Comment: Also thanks for your help on Christmas eve.

Comment: "Sorry for the long code, but to understand every part of it I had to provide a lot." Not at all! You could have demonstrated it in a single line [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): `if false | true; then echo "Why does this print?"; fi`. (Even if you're not able to reduce it that much by yourself, you certainly don't need an unused varable `LIGHTGRAY="\033[37m"` in order for people to understand what you mean.) People are still happy to help, but the most helpful and upvoted questions are usually short and to the point.

Comment: Check the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Usually, bash returns the exit code of the last command of a pipe group, so your `Debug` command was the one that was checked. With that setting, bash returns the exit status of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status. If your command fails, that is the status that get propagated.

Comment: @thatotherguy I would agree to disagree. I already understood the logic behind an if statement. Thus your example does not relate to my question/issue. I do however understand that I could of probably shorten my piece of code further and will edit it for you. My problem was trying to get the status of a command before the pipe.

Comment: @Poshi Thank you very much for your time and your explanation. I understand Bash better now. Unfortunately I can't just set your answer as my answer nor can I vote due to my lack of reputation on the site. I am fairly new to stack overflow.

Comment: My example seems to exactly reproduces your core problem, but I absolutely agree that the leap is not necessarily simple or obvious. Every simplification helps by taking away possible problems, both for you, for people who answer, and for future readers who find this question. Anyways, these posts are all comments and not proper answers (presumably because @Poshi wasn't sure if it was sufficient), and that's why you're unable to accept one. Poshi can post their suggestion as a proper answer, and then you'll be able to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @LouisOuellet you can't accept my answer because it was not an answer but a comment. It ws posted as a comment because it is just a tiny detail and because I was not able to test it before sending, so I could not be sure it was the real reason for your problem. But I can post it as an answer now so you can accept it.

Comment: @Poshi Yup your simple solution actually fixed my issue. So you can post it as answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `set -o pipefail`.

Check the manual: [The Set Builtin](http://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

Usually, bash returns the exit code of the last command of a pipe group, so your `Debug` command was the one that was checked. With that setting, bash returns the exit status of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status. If your command fails, that is the status that get propagated.